# Querying records not in through table

Tags: django, orm, many-to-many, django-queryset

Resuing Django example:

```
from django.db import models

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

How to I obtain all Articles that do not have publications?

```
Article.objects.filter(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify `publications` as None:

```
Article.objects.filter(publications=None)
```

Example:

```
>>> p1 = Publication.objects.create(title='1')
>>> p2 = Publication.objects.create(title='2')
>>> a1 = Article.objects.create(headline='a')
>>> a2 = Article.objects.create(headline='b')
>>> a3 = Article.objects.create(headline='c')
>>> a1.publications.add(p1)
>>> a1.publications.add(p2)
>>> a3.publications.add(p1)
>>> Article.objects.filter(publications=None)
[<Article: Article object>]
>>> _[0].headline
u'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Article.objects.filter(publications=None)
```

Define blank=True with publications field into Article model else it will not allow you to create article without publications.

```
publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication, blank=True)
```